# ASP.NET Core Web API HTTP GET - bind empty array and no array differently

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, model-binding, asp.net-core-3.0

I have a GET request that currently accepts a `Parameters` model bound from query:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class StuffController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("stuff")]
    public ActionResult<Stuff> GetStuff([FromQuery] Parameters parameters)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

```
public class Parameters
{
    [FromQuery]
    public int Number { get; set; }

    [FromQuery]
    public string[]? Filter { get; set; }
}
```

Passing some values to this array works as intended:

```
/api/stuff?number=42&filter=value1&filter=value2
```

results in `Filter = { "value1", "value2" }`.

But I'd like to distinguish no `filter` parameter from an empty `filter` parameter. So if it's not specified I'll get a `null`:

```
/api/stuff?number=42
```

but there is also a way to pass an empty array

```
/api/stuff?number=42&filter=[]
```

the above is not a valid and will result in a binding error, but I hope it gets across what I'm trying to achieve - my API needs to behave differently for no filters at all (so nothing will be filtered out) and for an empty filter (so *everything* will be filtered out).

Comment: What does `/api/stuff?number=42&filter=` result in (just drop the square brackets)?

Comment: @LGSon Results in a binding error `"The value '' is not valid."`

Comment: OK. I had a similar situation, with a single value, and used the word "all" to separate them.

Comment: What is your .net core api project version? I made a test with .net core 2.2 and .net core 3.0 preview 6, both of them works with `/api/stuff?number=42&filter=[]` to fill the `Parameters` with number = 42 and filter = `"[]"` There is no binding error. Share us a demo which could reproduce your issue.